# " java.lang.InternalError: The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects

Tags: swingx

I have made an desktop app in swing and it's not running. An exception has occur stating Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.InternalError: The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects. Please tell me the steps to resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read carefully [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should show your code, paste at least some stacktrace, not only the error message, tell us what you already  tried to resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

We can not help you if you don`t give us more information, post the lines of the code where de exception is occuring. Also check if you have too many swing components in the constructor of the window.